# Forming SQL Query and Passing The Result To The View

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this view method -

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var auctions = db.Auctions.ToArray();
        return View(auctions);  
    }
```

which correctly returns an array of all auctions in my database. But I want to return just the most popular ones.  I want to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var auctions = db.Auctions.getMostPopular.ToArray();
        return View(auctions);  
    }
```

Where getMostPopular() is a method in my model containing all my auctions and looks like so at the moment:

```
public static List<Auction> getMostPopular()
    {
       var query = "SELECT* FROM AUCTIONS WHERE EndTime > CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) ORDER BY viewCount DESC;" }
    }
```

So how do I correctly write this getMostPopular() method?
And is this the correct path to go writing it in the model?  Or should I write the query in the controller Index action, and if so what would that look like?

Comment: Why not try using `var auctions = getMostPopular().ToArray();` and change `getMostPopular` method to use LINQ (lambda) instead of raw SQL statement like this: `var query = db.Auctions.Where(x => x.EndTime > DateTime.Today).OrderByDescending(x => x.viewCount).ToList();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct is relative.  Your proposed SQL statement would seem to do the trick.  Ordering the results by the ViewCount desc would appear to be the main part of implementing your method get most popular.  If you're already considering a date filter, you might also consider the top clause such as select top 10 * from Table order by ViewCount desc, to only consider a fixed number of most popular items.